# sjplot's xtabs function gives error when trying to produce crosstabulation table

Tags: r, crosstab, sjplot

I've downloaded the lastest version of `sjplot` and `sjmisc`.  They aren't working correctly: I am unable to produce a simple crosstable of two variables:

```
sjt.xtab (mydataset$gender, mydateset$age)

Error: 'table_values' is not an exported object from 'namespace:sjmisc'
```

This is regardless of which of my variables I attempt to crosstab.  Oddly, if I use `sjp.xtab` it works fine, though with a warning message:

```
sjp.xtab (mydataset$gender, mydateset$age)

Warning message:
Deprecated, use tibble::rownames_to_column() instead.
```

Does anyone have any idea what I have to do to fix this?

Comment: I don't use these packages, but in base R, you could use `table(mydataset$gender, mydateset$age)` to get the cross tab or `xtabs(gender ~ age, data=mydataset)`.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but I think that sjplot creates visually much nicer tables than those

Comment: Are you sure you're using the latest packages (see also [here](https://github.com/sjPlot/devel/issues/170))? Could you please provide your sessionInfo()?  Maybe it is also an issue with the your R version - do you use the latest version?